# how to import access table in my-sql db using ssis as a bridge 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I'm just getting into SQL-server 2008 R2 ssis , so forgive me if this is a basic question. I'm building an application using integration service.

Want to create (SSIS) package for importing an MS Access table into My-SQL database.

[image]

To create ssis , I don’t want to use  Tasks...Import Data .

help me to import access table data to my-sql db.

If have any query plz ask ,thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

1 st you start with defining the connection managers.
You need one for MS Access and one for MySQL (I assume you use MySQL open source db engine as the destination).
Connecting to MySQL may be tricky. I know CozyRock's ODBC connection works with it: http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/odbc-destination, but you can try creating an ODBC one as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/03/03/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx. Make sure both conn managers connect.
From this point on, drag and drop a new Data Flow Task (DFT).
Inside the add a source and consume your MS Access table, you may need to also add a Derived Column Transformation to convert your incoming columns to some other data types MySQL understands, and finally drag and drop the destination which will employ your MySQL conn. manager. Connect all. Map the columns appropriately and test. If works repeat the aforementioned in a 2nd DFT to cover the import of the other table.